# updating category id for the product  instead of creating new id 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have two tables

product

```
                product_id
                product_Name
                product_Price
                product_Description
                product_image
                category_id
```

another table

```
                 category
                 category_id
                 category_name
                 category_description
```

i have a form with three text boxes(say tbProductPrice,tbProductName,tbProductdescription)  one combo box(cbcategorytypes) two buttons one edit and another one is save button..
i am trying update the product table along with category_id

when i click the edit button the category names are  loaded in the combobox

when we click on the save button what ever values in text boxes will be updated in product table along with category for that i  have done the below code...

```
              using (var vareditcontext = new abcEntities())
            {
                pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
                byte[] bit = null;

                bit = imageToByteArray(image);
                product1 pd = vareditcontext.product1.Where(p => p.product_Id == productid
                                     && p.category_Id == productcategoryid).First();


                string category = cbcategorytypes.Text;

                var c = new category { category_Name = category }; //problem at this line 

                pd.category = c;
                pd.product_Name = tbProductName.Text;
                decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(tbProductPrice.Text);
                pd.product_Price = price;
                pd.product_Description = tbProductdescription.Text;
                pd.product_Image = bit;
                vareditcontext.SaveChanges();                 
                this.Close();
            }
```

when i  click the save button i got an exception  like this ..

**Argument out of range exception**  ..

I am getting this error because when i edit and trying to save the product details  along with category name the new category name will be stored in database.....instead of updating the present one ...

how i can rectify this problem .. i mean not storing the new item i want to set the already exsiting category to the product...

is it possible with linq ....

would any one help on this..

many thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `category_id` is the `Key` property for your `category` entity. If you only load the `category_name` into the combobox you actually need to load the `Category` from the database because EF must know the key value when you assign the category to the product:

```
product1 pd = vareditcontext.product1
    .Where(p => p.product_Id == productid
        && p.category_Id == productcategoryid)
    .First();

category c = vareditcontext.categories
    .Where(cat => cat.category_name == cbcategorytypes.Text)
    .First(); // let's hope the name is unique to pick not the wrong one

pd.category = c;
// ...
vareditcontext.SaveChanges();
```

You could also only load the category_id and then leverage Dennis' approach to create a stub category and attach it to the context:

```
product1 pd = vareditcontext.product1
    .Where(p => p.product_Id == productid
        && p.category_Id == productcategoryid)
    .First();

int categoryid = vareditcontext.categories
    .Where(cat => cat.category_name == cbcategorytypes.Text)
    .Select(cat => cat.category_id)
    .First();

var c = new category { category_id = categoryid };
    // stub entity must have at least the key property set
vareditcontext.categories.Attach(c);

pd.category = c;
// ...
vareditcontext.SaveChanges();
```

If you would expose the `category_id` column in the `product` table as a foreign key property into your `product` model class you could just set the `category_id`:

```
product1 pd = vareditcontext.product1
    .Where(p => p.product_Id == productid
        && p.category_Id == productcategoryid)
    .First();

int categoryid = vareditcontext.categories
    .Where(cat => cat.category_name == cbcategorytypes.Text)
    .Select(cat => cat.category_id)
    .First();

pd.category_id = categoryid;
// ...
vareditcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either load the category from the context or attach the one you create on the fly to the context. Otherwise EF assumes you want to create and store a new one.

```
...
var c = new category { category_Name = category };
vareditcontext.Attach(c);
pd.category = c;
...
```

At MSDN, you can read more about [Attaching and Detaching Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx).

Comment: That's exactly what you do. `DbContext.Attach()` != `DbContext.Add()`. It doesn't add a new one, it attaches the one you create to the context, assuming it already exists the database, Sparing you the roundtrip to get it from the db. Read up on it, if things are still unclear.

Comment: Use `Add()` if you want to store a new object to the database. Use `Attach()` if you want to attach an object that resembles one that already exists in the database without the need to load it beforehand. Please follow the link in my answer and read the documentation, if you're still unsure.

Comment: This would be the easiest way **if** `category_name` is the primary key property. Who knows? If it's not, it doesn't work.

Comment: True. If the primary key is not known in this spot then the category or at least its key must be fetched from the database. Good point.